# Facebook - Share page with different image

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to specify a custom image when sharing? You used to be able to include `p[images][0]` in the url but that no longer works.

The problem is on a product page where the user can choose items in different colors and they may want to share the red image as opposed to the blue which is in `og:image` meta tag.

I am updating the `og:image` tag dynamically on image change but this is in the DOM and I don't think FB will see that change when scraping the page.

Answer (score 0):

Does your URL change? FB will scrap differently if URL is different. If blue bag, u can dynamically change og:image and URL www.example.com/order/bag/blue vs /red

Comment: No, the URL doesn't change, only the images within the page.

Comment: U have to change the URL dynamically in order for FB to detect and generate a new scrape. It tricks FB scraper to read the og:image again.

Comment: I did it with my website www.tell-my-friends.com/music/order/3149. The last uri segment changes with different product n FB reads the dynamic image.

Comment: Check your URL scrape results at Facebook debug or linter